# Howto use basic authentication in multi threaded HTTPClient environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, httpclient

I am trying to use HTTPClient to post a lot of requests to a webservice which is protected using basic authentication. Although I am using the ThreadSafeClientConnManager, the Basic Authentication implementations of the Apache HTTPClient does not seem to be thread safe. Sometimes the requesting header doesn't contain the authorization element, wich causes a 401.
Is there a common way or best practice to use Basic authentication with multiple threads?

Comment: When you say basic authentication, are you talking about just username/password, log in and get a session token, and you can reuse that session token for subsequent request? If that is the case I don't see how multi-threading can break things. Since you wont have a session ID before you can make subsequent requests.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about normal basic access authentication. There seems to be a problem when sharing the same http context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue recently.
There's this logged issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1168
You have two choices it seems:

1. Create an HttpContext for each thread or request
2. Use SyncBasicHttpContext which is a thread safe implementation

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it's a thread safety issue?  If you are using java.net.Authenticator, it caches names/passwords unless you do this:

```
AuthCacheValue.setAuthCache(new AuthCacheImpl());
```

AuthCacheValue and AuthCacheImpl are from sun.net.www.protocol.http.  I do this in the constructor of the class that extends Authenticator